# Proving a gcd equation: $\gcd(ab,c) \mid \gcd(a,c) \cdot \gcd(b,c)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

How would I be able to prove that $$\gcd(ab,c) \mid \gcd(a,c) \cdot \gcd(b,c)$$

I'm assuming I can start by saying $\gcd(ab,c) \cdot n = \gcd(a,c) \cdot \gcd(b,c)$ for some $n \in Z$ but I'm not sure how I can represent the $\gcd$ value as an integer combination of $a$ and $b$ to prove that the left side can divide the right side

Comment: Easiest, I think, to use unique factorization and the fact that the order of a prime $p$ in $\gcd (m,n)$ is the lesser of the orders of $p$ in $m,n$.

Comment: Hint: if $d\mid x$ and $d\mid y$, then $\gcd(x,y) = d\cdot \gcd(\frac xd,\frac yd)$. Apply this fact with $d=\gcd(a,c)$ and $x=ab$ and $y=c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\gcd(ab,c)$, we conclude that $\gcd(ab,c) \mid ab$ and $\gcd(ab,c) \mid c$. Now we will have two cases:

Case 1: $\gcd(ab,c) \mid a$ and $\gcd(ab,c) \mid c$:

In this case, we see that $\gcd(ab,c)$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $c$, so by definition of gcd, we have $\gcd(ab,c) \mid \gcd(a,c)$.

Case 2: $\gcd(ab,c) \mid b$ and $\gcd(ab,c) \mid c$:

Similarly, in this case we have $\gcd(ab,c)$ to be a common divisor of $b$ and $c$, so $\gcd(ab,c) \mid \gcd(b,c)$.

In either case, we will have $\gcd(ab,c) \mid \gcd(a,c) \cdot \gcd(b,c)$, and we are done.